# Publishing tile cache map service with full scale range without artificially over-sizing it on ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, scale, arcgis-rest-api, tilecache

I'm working within the ArcGIS platform including the ArcGIS Online account. I've got some high detailed orthophoto that I'd like to tile cache and than publish as a map service to my AGOL account.
When producing and tile caching, I'd rather not to generate an artificially over-sized cache that exceeds the maximum cell\pixel size of my original orthophoto because of storage considerations (700 MB that grows into 1.7 GB). Hence my cache file is produced in a certain scale range that fits its origins maximum cell size. After the cache has been produced and published as a map service in AGOL, it's scale range visibility is being automatically constrained to fit the level of details that it have been produced at.

---

**How can I make this map service to enable a larger scale range visibility that uses previous level of details?**

---

**Alternatively: How Can I produce and publish a map service that enables a larger scale range visibility and not artificially over-sizing my tiled cached orthophoto?**

---

The reason I'm trying to do it is that, though there is no actual additive data (restricting cell size) by further scaling, is that it's much better in terms of user interface (seeing the orthophoto in larger scale).

---

I've tried using the REST API interface and change the max scale by 'edit'. It change the definition but didn't seem to work within a web map. I've also tried to 'Update' the levels of details available to exceed itself but I've got this error `LOD not available for the level "8" Code: 500`

Comment: Have you seen this: How To: Set a custom scale range for a tile service in ArcGIS Online (http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012213)

Comment: Unfortunately yes...  This article discusses how to add more customize scales to the tiles production but it doesn't focus on how to use lower level of details with a higher scale.